# Exception while saving data into a txt file

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, file-writing

I am trying to write the data to a file, and the data is continuously updated every 100ms. So when I click save button then

**System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute.**

error comes up. Upon my search there is solutions to this probelm if there is `Foreach` loop but in my case there is no `Foreach` loop.

Bellow is the code I used

```
File.WriteAllLines(fileDialog.FileName, 
    RawDataFromSerialPort.Select((v, i) => $"{i + 1} Raw data is -->, {v.ToString()}"));
```

[image]

Comment: What type is `RawDataFromSerialPort` and how are you access it? You need to synchronize access to it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your serial port is still receiving data on a background thread whilst you're trying to read from the raw data collection, I'd suggest making a copy of the collection and then writing the copy out to the file.

Try using the syncroot property on the collection while doing the copy.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.syncroot?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Can you suggest some way to copy the whole collection before writing it into a file? I mean like you suggested I will have to copy and save collected data first with single click of a button SaveRawData @PhilH

Comment: I've updated, not being familiar with your program I can't say weather it's acceptable to lock the collection while copying though!

Answer (score 1):

Check the stacktrace as well, there you'll find the drill down of the call stack where eventually a foreach-(like)loop is used.

Click on the 'view details' link, expand the $exception node and look for the StackTrace field.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the List name I was accessing was wrong so correcting the list name `RawDataFromSerialPort` made my problem solved